# Order descending based on a maximum value of a group, and then remove the maximum column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose, in the `iris` data set, that I want to:

- Order by `Species` based on a column containing the maximum `Sepal.Length`, in descending order.
- Remove the maximum `Sepal.Length` column.
- Within each `Species`, keeping the order from the first step above, order `Sepal.Length` in descending order.

The following code yields the desired output:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(max.Sepal.length = max(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  arrange(desc(max.Sepal.length)) %>%
  select(-max.Sepal.length)

df[,"Species"] <- factor(df[,"Species"],
                         levels = unique(df[,"Species"]),
                         ordered = TRUE)

df <- df %>%
  arrange(Species, desc(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

However, suppose instead that I want to write this as a function:

```
df_order <- function(df, group_col, value_col) {
  df <- df %>%
    group_by({{ group_col }}) %>%
    mutate("max_{{value_col}}" := max({{value_col}}, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    arrange(desc("max_{{value_col}}")) %>%
    select(-"max_{{value_col}}")
  
  df[,"{{group_col}}"] <- factor(df[,"{{group_col}}"],
                           levels = unique(df[,"{{group_col}}"]),
                           ordered = TRUE)
  
  df <- df %>%
    arrange({{group_col}}, desc({{value_col}})) %>%
    as.data.frame()
  return(df)
}

df_order(iris, Species, Sepal.Length)
```

Alas, this doesn't work. Could someone point me to where my code is wrong? I am not extremely familiar with how `dplyr` has integrated with `glue`.

Comment: You can use the `{{` inside `dplyr` functions, but not inside plain base functions like `[`. Stay within `dplyr` and add your new columns with `mutate` rather than `df[, "{{group_col}}"]`.

Comment: Also, if you want to get rid of a grouping, use `ungroup()` not `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks. However, upon testing, the code does not execute the intended behavior starting at the first `arrange()` in my attempt. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Lastly, you *probably* don't want an ordered factor. All factors have a order for the levels. You really only need `ordered = TRUE` if you want a particular set of contrasts in a model where the 2nd level is compared to the 1st, the 3rd compared to the 2nd, etc., instead of the usual all levels are compared to the 1st level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to correct it - i.e. convert to `string` and use that string for wherever it needs

```
df_order <- function(df, group_col, value_col) {
   value_col_str <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(value_col))
   group_col_str <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(group_col))
   df <- df %>%
     group_by({{ group_col }}) %>%
     mutate("max_{{value_col}}" := max({{value_col}}, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
     as.data.frame() %>%
     arrange(desc(!! rlang::sym(glue::glue("max_{value_col_str}")))) %>%
     select(-glue::glue("max_{value_col_str}"))
  
   df[,group_col_str] <- factor(df[,group_col_str],
                            levels = unique(df[,group_col_str]),
                            ordered = TRUE)
  
   df <- df %>%
     arrange({{group_col}}, desc({{value_col}})) %>%
     as.data.frame()
   return(df)
 }
```

-testing

```
out <- df_order(iris, Species, Sepal.Length)
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
2            7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
3            7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica
4            7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica
5            7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica
6            7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica
7            7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
8            7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica
...

identical(out, df)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I get the impression that `arrange()` and `select()` don't work well with column-name concatenation and `{{}}`, and that `{}` (with a string input) is generally preferred. Would you say that's the case?

Comment: @Clarinetist it is not clear whether it works in a particular version of dplyr or not.  But, the string version should work in most versions.  The tidyverse function behavior can change from version to version though